# JSON to Knockout serializer on server

Tags: c#, json, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am using Web API in a current project. It returns a json string which is than converted to a knockout-observable by using the `knockout-mapping` plugin. I am wondering if this could not be done before, on the server side. For example:

Now a `GET` call to `\Product` returns the following:

```
{ Id: 2, Name: "Apple", Categories: ["fruit"] }
```

What I like to have directly returned by the server:

```
var data={ 
          Id: ko.observable(2), 
          Name: ko.observable("Apple"), 
          Categories: ko.observableArray([
              ko.observable("fruit")
          ])
};
```

Is there any .NET lib to do this? Or is there any way to extend the JSON.NET lib?

Comment: You'd be tightly coupling your back end to your front end technology choice.  That seems pretty risky based on how quickly the front end world is moving.

Comment: I was thinking about a odata formatter, so that the choice is by the api consumer. Who ever is using the api can use `$format=knockout` or not.

Comment: @JanHommes not advisable to do like that but here's the way http://knockoutmvc.com/ . cheers

Comment: @super cool Thanks for the link. Why is it not advisable in use with a OData formatter? It's just optional and JSON response would be still available and default.

Comment: @JanHommes Nice question but `ko.observable` is client-side function so even if you are able create the target syntax it will require to `eval` the response from ajax call..

Comment: @Harsh Baid Not if you directly implementing it into a script-tag, or am I wrong? This is my main goal ;)

Comment: `directly into a script-tag` you mean you will not use WebAPI and no AJAX call ?

Comment: @Harsh Baid still using web-api but no ajax call. Example: `<script src="https://domain.com/Product?$format=knockout">`

Comment: Well then why even use WebAPI ? you have Controllers (In MVC) or Page, Webcontrols (in WebForms) which can directly bind the data no need of knockout.js because knockout js is used to bind the data easily in frontend where data is get by using AJAX calls. I'm starting feel of Not-So-Smart-Question.. :( :P

Answer (score 0):

Although you could use an OData formatter, it could get difficult to maintain if your front end changes. You could essentially do the same thing on your front end by creating a viewmodel from your server's JSON:

```
function ViewModel(data)
{
    this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.Categories = ko.observableArray(data.Categories);
}
```

This way, as pointed out by Shane, you wouldn't have your back end tightly coupled with Knockout. Also, as a little side note to your categories, I wouldn't recommend setting each individual item in your array to an observable unless you need to observe each item.

Comment: Thanks, it was just an example. The ko.mapping plugin does exactly what I pointed out but on the client. So it should be faster if I do it on the server already and takeaway the complexity to the API consumer (which could be other than my frontend).